assert non-undefined property on a specific dictionary type definition
Having strictness options in my tsconfig.json, including strictNullChecks and noUncheckedIndexedAccess
and a type definition
type AlwaysHaveAnyProperties {
  [prop in string]: { a: Something }
}

compiler clearly complains when accessing
declare const dict:AlwaysHaveAnyProperties
dict.someProp.a //Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

I know I could use the non-null-assertion access dict.someProp!.a but that's unwanted as I'm using "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "error", and I'd be forced to disable that rule on each line I use AlwaysHaveAnyProperties
How can I define AlwaysHaveAnyProperties type that ensures the compiler any string property is always valued
[edit]:
to expand about the context:
as noted by first comments, the only sensible use case for such a request is for defining the behavior of a Proxy, and that's indeed my use case.

There is no such type in TypeScript that means "every possible property actually exists", which would be what, a Proxy? Requests for those are always declined as in ms/TS#22509. Index signatures dont mean "every string-keyed property exists and has type X", but "if a property has a string key, its type is X". Turning on noUncheckedIndeedAccess opts you into the undefined possibility. What you are asking for is therefore impossible in TS. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

Linter rules exist to make code better. If they prevent you from writing code that serves the purpose then using no-non-null-assertion rule is a mistake, disable it. Non-null assertions serve the purpose. Also consider providing the details on your case, an object that you describe is uncommon. As noted above, it should've been a proxy to behave like that

indeed, I definitely understand that for standard structures, such a definition would simply defy strictness rules, badly braking TS typesafety, however if the defining object is a Proxy - as you inferred ;) and that's indeed my use case - a specific definition like that would simply be correct and legit, isn't ?
I edited my question to clarify it's a Proxy use case

So do you agree that my comment fully addresses the question and I should write an answer explaining? Or did I miss something?

yes @jcalz thanks ! given the current TS feature-set, your well-referenced insight is responding correctly to my question!

There is no type in TypeScript that means "every property exists."
Your mapped type of the form {[K in string]: T} just results in an index signature of the form {[k: string]: T}. And this has only ever meant "if a property exists with a string key, then its type will be of type T".  With --noUncheckedIndexedAccess disabled, TypeScript "optimistically" assumes that when you check a property it will be there, so in some sense it looks like "every property exists", but that's just to make it easier to iterate objects, not because TypeScript really models the presence of every possible property.  When you enable --noUncheckedIndexedAccess, you're asking TypeScript to be "pessimistic" and so every time you read from an index signature, undefined is added to the domain of the property and you have to account for it. You turned that on, so you're asking for this type of checking.
The type you're looking for cannot currently be represented in TypeScript. No regular objects in JavaScript will have every possible key. That can only even appear to happen for Proxy objects, and TypeScript does not strongly model arbitrary Proxy object types. There is an open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#47594 to allow --noUncheckedIndexedAccess to be "turned off" for a particular type, in order to model Proxy objects.  It's currently listed as "Awaiting More Feedback", meaning they want to hear more about use cases before even considering implementing it. If you think your use case is more compelling than the ones already listed, you might want to add a comment describing it.  And/or give it a  to show your support for it. But unless there's a lot more community engagement with the issue, I wouldn't expect to see anything happen. It would add more complexity to the type system to deal with something that looks like an edge case.  Until and unless something changes, the current workaround of just using a non-null assertion or the like is the best approach here.
